# Angular 2 (SystemJS) XHR error (404 not found) /@angular/animations

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, typescript, primeng

I am new to Angular 2 and Type Script. in my project i am using PrimeNG UI controls.

I am getting following error in console when I run my APP.

Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:xxxxx/@angular/animations

Error loading http://localhost:xxxxx/@angular/animations as "@angular/animations" from http://localhost:xxxxx/node_modules//primeng/components/accordion/accordion.js

Below is my Systemjs.config.js file

```html
/**
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
    System.config({
        paths: {
            // paths serve as alias
            'npm:': 'node_modules/'
        },
        // map tells the System loader where to look for things
        map: {
            // our app is within the app folder
            app: 'app',

            // angular bundles
            '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
            '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
            '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
            '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
            '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
            '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
            '@angular/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade.umd.js',

            // other libraries
            'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
            'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js',
            'ng2-bs3-modal': 'npm:/ng2-bs3-modal',

            // Bootstrap
            'moment': 'node_modules/moment/moment.js',
            'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap': 'node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/bundles/ng2-bootstrap.umd.js',
            'primeng': 'npm:/primeng',
        },
        // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
        packages: {
            app: {
                main: './main.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            rxjs: {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            'ng2-bs3-modal': {
                main: '/bundles/ng2-bs3-modal.js', defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            'primeng': { defaultExtension: 'js' }
        }
    });
})(this);
```

Comment: make sure you have installed `@angular/animations` and please post your `system.config.js`

Comment: i have added my systemjs.config.js file. please check.

Answer (score 5):

You'll need 3 entries in systemjs.config.js

```
 "@angular/animations": "npm:@angular/animations/bundles/animations.umd.js",
    "@angular/animations/browser": "npm:@angular/animations/bundles/animations-browser.umd.js",
    "@angular/platform-browser/animations": "npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser-animations.umd.js",
```

You will also need to run

```
npm i @angular/animations --save
```

Comment: I will try this. Thanks.